# How can I change the user during a bash script execution?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have written a bash script from which i execute it from the root. I want to execute a particular command in a user account rather than root account.So how to execute that command in a user account and not in root account.For example i want to execute this command

```
echo 'user_pref("toolkit.networkmanager.disable", true);' >> ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js`
```

in a user account say `karthick` how to execute it?

Comment: In the case of appending a file, you could just append it as root, and the file will still be owned by the user. Hence, you don't really need either sudo or su in this specific case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo -u karthick 'echo \'user_pref("toolkit.networkmanager.disable", true);\' >> ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js`'
```

Most likely your problem can be solved more elegantly by some other means. Perhaps if you described that we could help solve the larger problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
su karthick -c "echo \'user_pref(\"toolkit.networkmanager.disable\", true);\' >> ~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/prefs.js"
```